# How to display checked images while scrolling the UITableView?

Tags: ios

UITable view is working fine. when scrolling checked image is changed to uncheck. And also i need to take the particular checked image data in SAVE button Action.Can any body help me to solve this problem in prj.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 20, 20)];
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        [cell addSubview:btn];
        btn.tag=4;
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        UILabel *lbl_name =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 100, 20)];
        lbl_name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr1 valueForKey:@"Name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        lbl_name.tag=5;
        lbl_name.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [lbl_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        lbl_name.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [cell addSubview:lbl_name];

    return cell;

}

-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]])
    {
        [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set images for different states of button like UIControlStateNormal  & UIControlStateSelected. Toggle the state of the button in you selector for button. This way you would not be required to do any check for the image name. Also, as long as the button is in memory, its state will be preserved, hence solving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one array which is Use to store IndexValue of Selected button,

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arySelected;
```

Initialize array in ViewDidLoad,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.arySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
```

Change Code of TableViewCell Delegate,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 20, 20)];

        if (![arySelected containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]])
        {
            [btn  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        }
        else
        {
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }

        btn.tag=indexPath.row;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:btn];

        UILabel *lbl_name =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 100, 20)];
        lbl_name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr1 valueForKey:@"Name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        lbl_name.tag=5;
        lbl_name.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [lbl_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        lbl_name.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [cell addSubview:lbl_name];

        return cell;
}
```

// On your button Event,

```
-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        [arySelected addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)sender.tag]];
    }
    else
    {
        [arySelected removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)sender.tag]];
    }


    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the deferent state to set image like this.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 20, 20)];
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
        btn.selected=NO;  
        btn.tag=4;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:btn];

        UILabel *lbl_name =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 100, 20)];
        lbl_name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr1 valueForKey:@"Name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        lbl_name.tag=5;
        lbl_name.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [lbl_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        lbl_name.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [cell addSubview:lbl_name];

    return cell;

}

-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
     if (tappedButton.isSelected) {
    tappedButton.selected=NO;
}
else
{
    tappedButton.selected=YES;
}
}
```